# Connecting to postgres on supabase via pgBouncer from prisma

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-run, prisma, supabase, pgbouncer

#### Problem

- running out of database connections in prod leading to errors like this;

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.queryRaw()` invocation:
  Timed out fetching a new connection from the connection pool. More info: http://pris.ly/d/connection-pool (Current connection pool timeout: 10, connection limit: 5)
    at Object.request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:45629:15)
    at async Proxy._request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:46456:18)
```

#### Situation

- multiple API containers running in Google Cloud Run running node/express/prisma API
- using Supabase's hosted postgres. In supabase Settings > Database, Connection Pooling is enabled.
- in db connection string, using `:6543/postgres?pgbouncer=true`

#### Attempt to diagnose

- in supabase, Database > Roles, I can see a list of roles and the number of connections for each. `pgBouncer` has 0 and the role which my application uses has several.
- If I query `pg_stat_activity`, I can see connections for the `usename` which is used by my application, and `client_addr` values representing ip addresses for a couple of different container instances. Are these "forwarded on" from `pgBouncer`? or have they bypassed `pgBouncer` entirely?

I am not familiar with what either of these should look like if I were using `pgBouncer` correctly so it's hard for me to tell what's going on.

I assume this means that I either haven't configured `pgBouncer` correctly, or I'm not connecting to it properly, or both. I'd be really grateful if someone could point out how I could either check or fix my connection to `pgBouncer` and clarify what I should see in `pg_stat_activity` if I was correctly connected to `pgBouncer`. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to daisy chain two poolers together in the first place?

Comment: The reported pg_stat_activity.client_addr would be the address of the pgbouncer instance if that is in use.  It does not masquerade as coming from the true end user.  Unless your pgbouncer is running on the same machines as your app servers, it apparently is being bypassed.

Comment: @jjanes when you say daisy chain two poolers, do you mean prisma and pgBouncer? I'm using prisma primarily as an ORM, but I don't think prisma's pooling alone is sufficient as there are multiple instance of the API running and therefore multiple instances of the prisma client.

pgBouncer is running on the supabase servers, not my Google cloud run instances, so that does confirm my suspicions that I'm not correctly connected to it - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what's going wrong here, so writing out how I fixed it in case anyone else runs into this issue.

#### Better understanding of the problem

in my prisma schema file I'm getting my database url from the env

```ts
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("SUPABASE_POSTGRES_URL")
}
```

and when I'm instantiating the prisma client I'm using the same variable

```ts
export const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: process.env.SUPABASE_POSTGRES_URL,
    },
  },
});
```

- I have a build trigger in Google Cloud Build that builds containers when branches that are merged into certain other branches, eg when PRs are merged in to master, build new containers and deploy them to prod.
- In the build trigger, the `SUPABASE_POSTGRES_URL` value is set in the env, using `:5432` which connects directly to postgres, bypassing pgBouncer. This is a requirement for prisma migrations which can't be run through pgBouncer.
- The Google Cloud Run container env vars specify a different value for `SUPABASE_POSTGRES_URL` however it looks like the this not being used, and instead the direct-to-postgres `:5432` value is used while the app is running, to connect to the db and run queries - so pgBouncer was permanently bypassed.

#### Solution

where the prisma client is instantiated, I'm using a second env var. It turns out that prisma uses the env var referenced in the schema file for the DB URL for migrations and the db url in the client instantiation for queries when the app is running, and you can happily have two completely separate values for these two URLs.

```ts
export const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: process.env.SUPABASE_PGBOUNCER_URL,
    },
  },
});
```

Now, `SUPABASE_POSTGRES_URL` is still populated from the build trigger, but it doesn't get used at runtime; instead I set `SUPABASE_PGBOUNCER_URL` in the Google Cloud Run env vars and that gets used during the prisma client instantiation, so queries a run through pgBouncer.

#### Result

- Effective Prisma migrations direct to postgres
- Effective connection pooling by running queries through pgBouncer

Comment: Hey @sauntimo. I have set the pgBouncer query parameter to true. Is that the extent of configuration I need or do I need to set up pgBouncer in my database, or application, or what?

Comment: @Leafyshark, you would need to configure pg_bouncer in your postgres instance - it's a postgres extension. If you're using supabase like I was here, I believe it's on by default for newer databases, but you can check in the settings